# Regular savings account interest calculation php

Tags: php, math, formula, calculator

OK, I've had the same problem for a few weeks now and cant perfect it.

**Aim**

To build a regular deposit savings account system where it prints out the total balance at the current time.

**Problem**

The current equation I have:

If the interest is **6%** with the user paying in **200** a month with compound being each month the balance would be after 6 months ***1,220.61***

I am getting ***1217.13***

I have tested different lengths of time and many different online calculators, my calculation is always less.

**My code**

```
<h2>Total Balance To Date</h2>
    <?php

    $p = 0; // Starting amount
    $i = 0.06; // Interest rate
    $c = 12; // compound frequency set to monthly
    $n = 6/12; // Current time invested set to 6 months
    $r = 200; // Monthly investment is 200

    $x = $i / $c;
    $y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));

    if($p!=0)
    {
        $vf = $p * $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);
    }
    else
    {
        $vf = 1 + $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);
    }

    ?>

    <p>£<?php echo round($vf, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); ?></p> // Comes out at 1217.13
```

**LINK to sandbox** https://3v4l.org/9X7OH

Comment: I get 1215.10, so...

Comment: I get 1020.17587763 before rounding...

Comment: @MarcB: Looks like you forgot to calculate last month, I guess.

Comment: no, I ran this exact code in my php, and get $vf = `float(1215.1003757506)
`

Comment: Ill add a link to sandbox

Comment: ah right. $p!=0. well, $vf comes out to 1215.10 or 1216.13 either way. neither are 1217.13

Comment: I calculated by myself (didn't use that method)

Comment: Either way, using other online calculators i should get 1,220.61 not 1216 or 1215, can anyone see where the calculation has gone wrong ? I understand that the calculation above may print 1217 but how would i work out compound interest correctly then ?

Comment: How should the result be 1,220.61?

Comment: I have lots of calculators online that tell me that is should be 1220, so the main part of the question, is my way of working out compound interest correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
q = pow(1.06 , 1.0/12) = 1.0048675505653430
```

and computing

```
200*(q+q^2+q^3+q^4+q^5+q^6) = 200*q*(q^6-1)/(q-1)
```

gives the result

```
1220.61037336530790
```

which is obviously what the online calculators worked with. It is slightly wrong, as for the nominal interest rate, the monthly compound factor should be

```
q = 1 + 0.06/12 = 1.005
```

resulting in a balance after 6 months of

```
1221.1758776293781
```

---

As you see, you got the formula almost right, it should be

```
$vf = $p * $y + ($r * (1 + $x) * ($y - 1) / $x);
```

since the rate is deposited at the start of the month, so the first rate gets compounded as `r*(1+x)^6` and the last rate as `r*(1+x)`. However, the second formula in the `else` branch does not make sense at all.

Comment: this looks fantastic, Im working on something atm. but later il try this and when it works ill happily accept your answer, thanks again.

Comment: I can confirm it works brilliantly, so glade the if statement is not needed, thank you.